# Weak stochastic integral

Tags: integration, reference-request, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, weak-derivatives

I recently encountered the following object, referred to as "weak stochastic integral" in the book of SPDE's by Prévôt/Röckner [PR07]:

$$ \int_0^T \langle \Psi \,\mathrm dW(t), \Phi(t)\rangle $$

A few useful properties are stated and a representation in terms of a "classical real valued Ito integral, namely $ \int_0^T \tilde{\Psi}_\Phi \, \mathrm dW(t)$, are given, under suitable assumption and for a suitably defined operator $\tilde{\Psi}_\Phi$ (see chapter 2 in [PR07]).

Does anyone have further references where I can find something more about it?

Moreover, is there any known formal results in the direction of proving that something like an integration by parts, as, for example

$$ \int_0^T \langle \mathrm dW(t), \Phi(t) \rangle = \int_0^T \langle W(t), -\mathrm d\Phi(t) \rangle + \langle W(t),\Phi(t) \rangle  \Big|_0^T $$

can be performed?

Thanks

[PR07] *A Concise Course on Stochastic Partial Differential Equations*,
 Lecture Notes in Mathematics, Vol. 1905
Claudia Prévôt and Michael Röckner, 2007.

Comment: did you ask on mathoverflow?